# Convert all columns from character to numeric except two

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Steve  2005   2006  2007  2008  2009  2010  Adam
134     24     42    45    56    43    32    54
#With 50 more rows
```

What I would like to do is to transform all these columns as numeric except for Steve and Adam who are going to stay as character.

This function have I found but it transforms all of the columns to numeric.

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `across` with `-` to select columns other than the 'Steve', 'Adam'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(-c(Steve, Adam), as.numeric))
```

If we need the `is.character` as well

```
df %>%
    mutate(across(c(where(is.character), -c(Steve, Adam)), as.numeric))
```